# How to interpret sybase RESTRICT Operator (VA = 1)(4)(0)(0)(0)(0)

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Can someone help to clarify restrict operator?

I understand Sybase restrict operator is used to evaluate expressions based on columns. But I still can't figure out the exact meaning of RESTRICT Operator  in the query plan.

e.g, below is a query plan snippet of my sql.  RESTRICT Operator (VA = 1)(4)(0)(0)(0)(0):  what does (4)(0)(0)(0)(0) mean?

```
    10 operator(s) under root



   |ROOT:EMIT Operator (VA = 10)

   |

   |   |SCALAR AGGREGATE Operator (VA = 9)

   |   |  Evaluate Ungrouped COUNT AGGREGATE.

   |   |

   |   |   |N-ARY NESTED LOOP JOIN Operator (VA = 8) has 7 children.

   |   |   |

   |   |   |   |RESTRICT Operator (VA = 1)(4)(0)(0)(0)(0)

   |   |   |   |

   |   |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 0)

   |   |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE

   |   |   |   |   |  trade

   |   |   |   |   |  t

   |   |   |   |   |  Index : i1

   |   |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.

   |   |   |   |   |  Positioning by key.

   |   |   |   |   |  Keys are:

   |   |   |   |   |    order_number ASC

   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for index leaf pages.

   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for index leaf pages.

   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.

   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.

   |   |   |

   |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 2)

   |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE

   |   |   |   |  product

   |   |   |   |  mp

   |   |   |   |  Index : mp

   |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.

   |   |   |   |  Positioning by key.

   |   |   |   |  Keys are:

   |   |   |   |    prod_id ASC

   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for index leaf pages.

   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for index leaf pages.

   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.

   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.

   |   |   |

   |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 3)

   |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE

   |   |   |   |  Accounts

   |   |   |   |  a

   |   |   |   |  Index : i2

   |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.

   |   |   |   |  Positioning by key.

   |   |   |   |  Index contains all needed columns. Base table will not be read.

   |   |   |   |  Keys are:

   |   |   |   |    account ASC

   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for index leaf pages.

   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for index leaf pages.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the showplan output, like those numbers behind the operator, are internals of the ASE optimizer. There is no documented information about these, and this information is included to help techsupport in resolving issues. 
The 'VA = n' part is just reflecting the unique number 'n' for every operator in the query plan.

Comment: Indeed, there is no Sybase documentation about these.